# Rewrite SQL Code Using a Join Instead of Subquery

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm having trouble visualizing how subqueries would look in the form of joins instead. In particular, the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName
FROM Employees e 
INNER JOIN Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT c.Country
  FROM Customers c
  WHERE c.Country = e.Country
)
```

It would greatly be appreciated if I could receive some tips on what to do when I want to turn a statement with a subquery into a join instead.

Comment: .... you need _a_ subquery, since `Customers` is likely to contain duplicate countries.  And you probably also want to move `Orders` in there as well, if you don't pull any data from it, so that your `DISTINCT` is on the inner subquery.

Comment: ... and in the case of `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT ... Orders JOIN Customers ...)` in the subquery, you dont **need** a distinct, since you are only selecting from employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful about duplicates, but the transformation for `EXISTS` is quite direct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName
FROM Employees e INNER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT c.Country
      FROM Customers c
     ) c
     ON  c.Country = e.Country
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks clean. In fact, it is not:

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName
FROM Employees e
JOIN Orders o ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
JOIN Customers c ON c.Country = e.Country
        ;
```

---

The point is that if there are more than one matching rows for `orders` and `Customers`, these will all cause a seperate copy of the `Employee` record to be merged. These will later have to be suppressed by the`DISTINCT`(the optimiser might catch this, or it might not)

---

The point is: you dont need a distinct, since you are only selecting columns from employee:

---

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName
FROM Employees e 
WHERE EXISTS( 
  SELECT * FROM Orders o
  WHERE o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
  )
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM Customers c
  WHERE c.Country = e.Country
  );
```

---

Or,in a more or less **ugly style**:

---

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName
FROM Employees e 
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT c.Country
  FROM Orders o
  JOIN Customers c
  ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
  AND c.Country = e.Country
);
```